# how to namespace many events in a Javascript object literal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery events to capture events across a rails app. Basically, there are a set of event captures' on DOM elements that then call other functions. What I'd like to do is provide some namespacing to these event captures and an looking for the best way:

I currently have (but like 60 of them):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.edit-item').on('click', arc.event_handler.edit_item);
});
```

and would like something like the following - basically provide the edit_item so we know where to look:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var events.edit_item= {
    $('.edit-item').on('click', arc.event_handler.edit_item);
  };
});
```

But this is giving me an error. I am familiar with basic object literal syntax like:

```
var my = {
  say_my_name: function(){
    alert('my name');
  }
}
```

but not sure how to apply it with jQuery functions. How would I do this?

I am aware that there are anonymous functions for namespacing this more agressively but, honestly, just want this one change right now

thx in advance

Comment: These are not event capturing, but bubbling, the title is misleading

Comment: @vsync you can edit if you want. to be honest, there was a secondary bug that was causing the issue (although this was 4 years ago)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want

```
var events = {
    "edit_item": $('.edit-item').on('click', arc.event_handler.edit_item)
};
```

or

```
var events = {};
events.edit_item = …;
// equal to
events["edit_item"] = …; // Here you could use any expression (like a variable) 
                         // instead of the string literal
```

Now `events.edit_item` is the jQuery object returned by the expression.

Comment: But I think he needs a *single* object with all returned objects by the many event-handlers...

Comment: hmm... thx, so i think I made a REALLY stupid mistake. It seems that the above from Bergi works and that my problem was the semi-colon at the end. So this answer works but if I could ask another question. What is the value / importance of "edit_item"; it looks like it could be "something_else" or a variable like e or my_var?

Comment: `"edit_item"`, the property name, needs to be a static string value in object literals, you can't use a variable. You might omit the quotes if the name doesn't lead to a syntax error.

Comment: I just looked up at jQuery what `on()` returns, but didn't understand it. Why do you need the return value of `on()`?

Comment: @nalply: `on()` returns, like many other jQuery function, the object it just operated on - so you could store it or call more methods on it ("chaining"). I don't know for what the OP needs it here

Comment: Yes I studied the source code. Thank you. We are all here to learn.

Comment: our on is basically delegating to a json call

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is useful:

```
var events;
$(document).ready(function(){
  events = {
    edit_item: $('.edit-item').on('click', arc.event_handler.edit_item),
    other_item: $('.other-item').on(/* something else */),
    //... 
    // the last item without trailing comma
  };
});
```

Please note the commas at the end of the lines. IE however dislikes the comma after the last line, so omit it.

The events object contains the jQuery objects, so you can bind more events to it or do other jQuery operations on them.